# Keep Facebook Messenger online in the background

Tags: facebook

I own a Lumia 625. When I am not using the Facebook Messenger app its running in the background. However it doesn't show me as online to my contacts. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It might not show online because the app isn't running in foreground. I mean you're not using it at the time. But, your friends should see a messenger sign(a bolt sign) to show that you are using messenger and, so, will be notified when they send a message. And basically you get notified because the app is running in background. So, you might not be shown as online, but as available to get notified about messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Open Messenger
2. Go to active page
3. Tap on "chat" and then tap "turn on chat"

Answer (score -1):

Long press back button, swipe left to reach Messenger window. Don' click on it yet. Swipe it down and you're back to the main window of tiles. That means the messenger is closed. You can do the same for any app.

Answer (score -1):

of course, you are offline now. Running app background helps you can receive push emails and messages.